# Mediawiki migration error: relation "page" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, mediawiki

I have migrated mediawiki from CentOS 5 to CentOS 6, from Postgres 8.1 to Postgres 8.4.

Everything was fine, until I wanted to acces my main page.
When I do, the following error appears:

```
> A database error has occurred Query: SELECT
> page_id,page_namespace,page_title,page_restrictions,page_counter,page_is_redirect,page_is_new,page_random,page_touched,page_latest,page_len FROM page WHERE page_namespace = '0' AND page_title = 'Main_Page'
> LIMIT 1  Function: Article::pageData Error: 1 ERROR: relation "page"
> does not exist LINE 1: ...ge_random,page_touched,page_latest,page_len
> FROM page WHER... ^ Backtrace:
> 
> #0 /var/www/html/mediawiki_svn/includes/db/Database.php(616): DatabasePostgres->reportQueryError('ERROR: relatio...', 1, 'SELECT
> page_id...', 'Article::pageDa...', false)
> #1 /var/www/html/mediawiki_svn/includes/db/Database.php(1026): Database->query('SELECT page_id...', 'Article::pageDa...')
> #2 /var/www/html/mediawiki_svn/includes/db/Database.php(1106): Database->select('page', Array, Array, 'Article::pageDa...', Array,
> Array)
> #3 /var/www/html/mediawiki_svn/includes/Article.php(369): Database->selectRow('page', Array, Array, 'Article::pageDa...')
> #4 /var/www/html/mediawiki_svn/includes/Article.php(381): Article->pageData(Object(DatabasePostgres), Array)
> #5 /var/www/html/mediawiki_svn/includes/Wiki.php(300): Article->pageDataFromTitle(Object(DatabasePostgres), Object(Title))
> #6 /var/www/html/mediawiki_svn/includes/Wiki.php(60): MediaWiki->initializeArticle(Object(Title), Object(WebRequest))
> #7 /var/www/html/mediawiki_svn/index.php(116): MediaWiki->initialize(Object(Title), NULL, Object(OutputPage),
> Object(User), Object(WebRequest))
> #8 {main}
```

When I checked the database I could find the tables: objectcache and page

Any ideas?

Comment: Why did you migrate from one completely outdated and obsolete Postgres version to another completely outdated and unsupported Postgres version?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name

Migration purpose is to archive valuable information, until the information has been assigned a new data container other than mediawiki.
I have installed 8.4 because I made the incorrect assumption that the DB migration would go flawless, but beyond 8.3 there are some changes within tsearch2. So yes, I can have installed 9.x, but the problem would not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the mediawiki static since it is going to be archived.